# How to beginBitmapFill without repeats?(AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

my code:

myCircle = new Shape();

```
function doStuffWithBitmapData(bmd:BitmapData):void
        {

            myCircle = new Shape();
            var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.translate(0, 0);
            myCircle.graphics.beginBitmapFill(bmd, matrix, false);
            myCircle.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 17);
            myCircle.graphics.endFill();
            myCircle.x = 40;
            myCircle.y = 63;

            addChild(myCircle);

            // your code

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
        }

        private function onEnterFrame(e:Event)
        {
            myCircle.rotation += 3;


        }
```

I need to fill the circle with image , but the image is repeating many times, but if I set the repeat to false, the picture will be bigger, can I make no repeat and at the same time don't change the sizes of the filled image?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not too sure of the the bitmapfill method, but creating your own bitmap and bitmapData, and then using your image's bitmapdata, you can manipulate the image pixel/data anyway you like.

-Using the setPixel/setPixel32 method of the bitmapData class will be helpful in your task (google is your friend)

Adobe's help: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html

Answer (score 0):

Please look closely at the **`draw()`** method of BitmapData Class Documents. It is very important.

and refer a following code.

```
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.Bitmap;

var myCircle:Shape;

var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(600,400,false,0xffffff);
var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd);
this.addChild(bmp);

var circleBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(20,20,false,0xffffff * Math.random());

myCircle = new Shape();
var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
myCircle.graphics.beginBitmapFill(circleBitmapData);
myCircle.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 20);
myCircle.graphics.endFill();
myCircle.x = 40;
myCircle.y = 63;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

function onEnterFrame(e:Event)
{
    bmd.draw(myCircle, myCircle.transform.matrix, myCircle.transform.colorTransform);
    myCircle.x = Math.random() * stage.width;
    myCircle.y = Math.random() * stage.height;
}
```